# What is the easiest way to upgrade Windows 7 Professional 64 bit to Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64 bit at the minute, I now have an MSDN subscription which allows me to use Windows 7 Ultimate.

Should I just download Windows 7 Ultimate, burn it to a disc, boot from the disc and select upgrade, do a clean install or is there some option within Windows for this. Really all I am doing is adding bitlocker so you would think there is some option within Windows.

I am competent with installing and configuring Windows, so this isn't a skill issue, I am just looking for the path of least resistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime Upgrade Using An Already Purchased Retail Pro/Ultimate Key

In Windows 7 Home Premium, type Anytime Upgrade in the Search programs and files box in the Start menu and click on the Windows Anytime Upgrade icon.  From there, you can enter your retail (Full or Upgrade) Windows 7 Professional/Ultimate product key and perform a simple upgrade. All programs and files will stay on the computer, no disk is needed and it takes about 10 minutes.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-anytime-upgrade

Source: [Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/w7itproinstall/thread/71ca232d-c721-4b0c-8385-b877fe9c003e)

Comment: Just tried! Apparantly MSDN retail license keys don't work with Anytime Upgrade!

Comment: Ah OK, didn't realise the MSDN keys didn't work with AU sorry.

Comment: This did actually work in the end, Anytime Upgrade told me that the key wasn't valid so I exited out and gave up on the idea, a few days later (I run a number of services on my PC so don't restart that often) I restarted my PC having forgot about the whole thing to find that I was running Ultimate?! Maybe a glitch?

Answer (score 0):

I would just go ahead and burn the CD, then boot into it and select 'Upgrade'. Sounds like the easiest way to do it, and it should work.